# java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFED in android?

Tags: java, android, datasource, mediametadataretriever

Here is my code:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever metadataRetriever;
metadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
metadataRetriever.setDataSource(mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

I get exception like this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 3247): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFED
E/AndroidRuntime( 3247):        at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3247):        at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:70)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3247):        at com.skyworth.tvfileexplorer.utils.FileUtils.getPreview(FileUtils.java:544)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3247):        at com.skyworth.tvfileexplorer.app.folders.CardPreviewer.doInBackground(CardPreviewer.java:33)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3247):        at com.skyworth.tvfileexplorer.app.folders.CardPreviewer.doInBackground(CardPreviewer.java:13)
```

Comment: What does mediaFile.getAbsolutePath() resolve to?

Comment: @WilliamSeemann  mediaFile.getAbsolutePath() just return the file path, for example: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/test.mp4. I think I know the problem, it is because `setDataSource` accept `Uri` as parameter instead of `file path`. But how can I get uri of a media file?

Comment: setDataSource requires a protocol. Just append "file://" to the beginning of the path.

Comment: @WilliamSeemann yes, you are right. I do try this method many many times, then I find that android `MediaPlayer` cannot recognize my mp4 file! I just change a mp4 file, it works. But I can play the video in windows, why both mp4, one can play while the other cannot?

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error when redefining the MediaMetadataRetriever a number of times. Changed this to have a single static declaration and the problem has gone away. Using 4.4.2.